# How to use foreach() in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get the following error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

for the following code:

```
    <?php

$connection=mysqli_connect(/*hostname*/"localhost",
                    /*username*/"u",
                    /*password*/"p",
                    /*database name*/"d");

try {

    // Setting the query and runnin it...
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `category` = 5 ORDER BY 3";
  $result = $connection->query($sql);

  // Iterating over the data and printing it.
  foreach($result as $row) {
      echo $row['rowa']. ' - '. $row['rowb']. ' - '. $row['rowc']. ' - '. $row['rowd']. ' - '. $row['rowe'].'<br />';
  }
  // Closing the connection.
  $connection = null;
}
// Catching it if something went wrong.
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
} ?>
```

How do I fix this error and is there anything else wrong with the coding?

Comment: `$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` and then put `$rows` in `foreach()`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Comment: syntax error, may be you forgot to put `;` after `$rows` declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, your usage of `foreach()` is correct. However, it won't work with results returned by a SQL query.

Instead, you'll have to use another loop, e.g. something like this:

```
while ($row = function_taking_one_result($result)) {
    // your own handling of $row
}
```

For `function_taking_one_result()` you've got a few built-in function calls handling the returned results in different ways (see documentation).

What you're most likely looking for is `mysqli_fetch_row()` which will return a PHP array using the column names as keys and the row's data as values. This function will return `FALSE` once there aren't any further results (and therefore leave the loop).

Comment: I recieved this error:  Call to undefined function function_taking_one_result()

Comment: It's just a placeholder. Use `mysqli_fetch_row()` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use it in this way:

```
foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row) {
  echo $row['rowa']. ' - '. $row['rowb']. ' - '. $row['rowc']. ' - '. $row['rowd']. ' - '. $row['rowe'].'<br />';
```

}

EDIT:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
if($result)
{ 
  foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row) {
  echo $row['rowa']. ' - '. $row['rowb']. ' - '. $row['rowc']. ' - '. $row['rowd']. ' - '. $row['rowe'].'<br />';
  }
}else{
 echo "QUERY IS NOT OK";
}
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given @user3091574

Comment: @TheOkayMan I have edited the answer. Now What output you are getting??

Comment: @TheOkeyMan well then your query is not ok, check for your query

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `category` = 5 ORDER BY 3"; 'what does the WHERE `category` = 5 ORDER BY 3 mean'

Comment: @TheOkayMan It means select all rows whose category is 5 and then sort  them in ascending order based on 3rd column

Comment: would that change the query?

Answer (score 0):

The query() method returns an resource identifier not ARRAY. so you cant loop over non array thing. foreach loop can be used only for Arrays.

After running the query you need to fetch the data in array and then try running it on loop.
Its better if you use while() loop for db arrays.

for ex:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `category` = 5 ORDER BY 3";

$qry = $connection->query($sql); //Runs the query but wont fetch RESULT

  // Iterating over the data and printing it.
while($row=$qry->fetch_array()) {
//or $qry->fetch_assoc(), $qry is the variable used to execute query. check above line
echo $row['rowa'].'-'. $row['rowb'].'-'.$row['rowc'].'-'.$row['rowd'].'-'.$row['rowe'].'<br />';
  }
```